# Should I trim outliers from input features

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Almost half of my input feature columns have offshoot "outliers" like when the mean is **19.6** the max is **2908.0**. Is it OK or should I trim those to `mean + std`?

```
              msg_cnt_in_x  msg_cnt_in_other         msg_cnt_in_y \
count             330096.0           330096.0            330096.0   
mean                  19.6                2.6                38.3   
std                   41.1                8.2                70.7   
min                    0.0                0.0                 0.0   
25%                    0.0                0.0                 0.0   
50%                    3.0                1.0                 8.0   
75%                   21.0                2.0                48.0   
max                 2908.0             1296.0              4271.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general answer to that. It depends very much on your probem and data set.

You should look into your data set and check whether these outlier data points are actually valid and important. If they are caused by some errors during data collection you should delete them. If they are valid, then you can expect similar values in your test data and thus the data points should stay in the data set.

If you are unsure, just test both and pick the one that works better.